# PHP: Variable showing value, even when submit button hasn't been clicked

Tags: php, mysql

The scenario is that one must search the code, and the results will appear from the MySQL DB if the code is present, otherwise display a message "Sorry, but there were no results found" is displayed. Perhaps re-enter your EVR No.: or double check your entry."

However, before the search is even made, the error message is already shown.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $no_results = NULL;
    $query = (isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : null);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evrdata WHERE evr_no = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){            
          $evr_no ='<br/>EVR No. :  '.'<b>'.$results['evr_no'].'</b>';
          $surname ='<br/>Surname :  '.'<b>'.$results['surname'].'</b>';
          $othername ='<br/>First Names :  '.'<b>'.$results['othername'].'</b>';
          $ps_code ='<br/>PS Code :  '.'<b>'.$results['ps_code'].'</b>';

        }
    }
    else { // if there is no matching rows do following
        $no_results = '<br/>Sorry, but there were no results found. Perhaps re-enter your EVR No.: or double check your entry.</b>';        
    }

?>
```

and on the same file, in HTML where the results are to appear:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="search">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your EVR No." required/>
                 <button type="submit" id="form-submit" value="Search" class="btn-submit btn btn-big dark-blue-bordered-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <?php 
                 if($no_results!="") // Two times Doule Quotation marks that is, and != means "not equal to". So we mean to say if $code is not equal to empty
                 {
                     echo $no_results;
                 }
                 else { echo " "; }
```

I have tried isset(), empty() but the error message still shows even though the search hasn't been made.

What am I missing?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: $_POST['query'] is empty most likely. Hence the SQL query fails. Make an if-clause surrounding the whole SQL stuff, add it before the $query line. if $_POST['query'] is set and strlen of post['query'] is not null, proceed.

Comment: Yes it is, until the submit button is clicked on.What can be done to prevent this?

Comment: As I said, surround the PHP code into an if/else statement.

Comment: shouldnt you put whole php part in `if(isset($_POST['query']))` ? because now you do search even if there no $_POST['query']...

Comment: I just posted my answer with the idea I had.

Comment: @Janno sorry, we did that in almost same time :/ should I remove it?

Comment: Nah it's okay, doesn't matter.

Comment: @Janno you should add `mysql_real_escape_string` :)

Comment: He also should use PDO or MySQLi, hence why I didn't add any other safe stuff in it, seems that he doesn't mind it that much.

Comment: @Janno You know, when you're just learning, the main thing is write code that it work. At least it was when I started :) security comes later.

Comment: It's best to write code which is safe from the get-go, so you wouldn't have to re-learn the functions etc how they work later on, hence, why he should start using PDO or MySQLi straight away instead of still working on the deprecated version.

Comment: @Janno It's possible to use even pdo unsafely ;D many times I have seen that people puts strings in query instead of escaping them. Okay, I am stopping this discussion, you're right.

Comment: True, you can make everything unsafe if you do it wrong, but atleast step one would still be to move away from deprecated functions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its rough, but that will do. 
The reason is when page is loaded, your search box is empty and is executing the query with NULL returning 0 rows.

```
<?php
$no_results = NULL;
$query = (isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : null);

if ($query) {
     $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evrdata WHERE evr_no = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

     if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

     while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){            
      $evr_no ='<br/>EVR No. :  '.'<b>'.$results['evr_no'].'</b>';
      $surname ='<br/>Surname :  '.'<b>'.$results['surname'].'</b>';
      $othername ='<br/>First Names :  '.'<b>'.$results['othername'].'</b>';
      $ps_code ='<br/>PS Code :  '.'<b>'.$results['ps_code'].'</b>';

    }
  }
  else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    $no_results = '<br/>Sorry, but there were no results found. Perhaps re-enter your EVR No.: or double check your entry.</b>';        
}
}
```

?>

Comment: I think its better to do check if `$_POST['query']` exists and then simply write `$query = $_POST['query']` (in my way). then we have 1 if instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$no_results = NULL;
if (isset($_POST['query']) && strlen($_POST['query']) > 0) {
$query = (isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : null);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evrdata WHERE evr_no = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){            
      $evr_no ='<br/>EVR No. :  '.'<b>'.$results['evr_no'].'</b>';
      $surname ='<br/>Surname :  '.'<b>'.$results['surname'].'</b>';
      $othername ='<br/>First Names :  '.'<b>'.$results['othername'].'</b>';
      $ps_code ='<br/>PS Code :  '.'<b>'.$results['ps_code'].'</b>';

    }
}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    $no_results = '<br/>Sorry, but there were no results found. Perhaps re-enter your EVR No.: or double check your entry.</b>';        
}
} else {
     //no query value
}
```

?>

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to retain the EVR number in the form when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Will stop using deprecated functions, and will update to MySQLi. Thanks

Comment: Yes.

Inside your HTML file: <input type="text" name="query" value=<?php echo $query; ?> class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your EVR No." required/>

Comment: That expects you to initialize $query before the if clause which you can see in my post. Otherwise you'll see a warning about an uninitialized variable when you get on the page. But this will work (should atleast).

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="search">
           <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your EVR No." required/>
                     <button type="submit" id="form-submit" value="Search" class="btn-submit btn btn-big dark-blue-bordered-btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your EVR No." required/>

Here just put the value=<?php echo $query; ?>

<input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your EVR No." value="<?php echo $query; ?> required/>

Comment: Ah! Right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
$no_results = '';
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);//added some security

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evrdata WHERE evr_no = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){            
          $evr_no ='<br/>EVR No. :  '.'<b>'.$results['evr_no'].'</b>';
          $surname ='<br/>Surname :  '.'<b>'.$results['surname'].'</b>';
          $othername ='<br/>First Names :  '.'<b>'.$results['othername'].'</b>';
          $ps_code ='<br/>PS Code :  '.'<b>'.$results['ps_code'].'</b>';

        }
    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        $no_results = '<br/>Sorry, but there were no results found. Perhaps re-enter your EVR No.: or double check your entry.</b>';        
    }
}
?>
```

This should be the best choice... stop using mysql_* functions use PDO or MySQLi. Your code IS **VULNERABLE** to sql-injection